# Restrict Access to Contact Record

Tags: permissions, relationships

Is it possible to restrict access to specific contact records? I understand that we can place people into groups, but in certain confidential situations, I only need specific users to not be able to access the contact record.

The only way I can think of is to create groups for each contact record but that seems to be too crazy.

Comment: "create groups for each contact record" yep that would be crazy

Comment: hmm was just googling for an extension which let you set some contacts as eg VIP and that would restrict them from everyone without super powers but not finding it. my google foo has run low. also read up about ACLs if you have not already